# How can I call a function from another .dll which is injected to the same program?

Tags: c++, dll, directx-9

My question is really above, I will give more information on this below however:

I have a program which first takes my "false" d3d9.dll, this DLL is then loaded into the game I am reverse engineering. After the some time and the .dll is loaded, along with all the other games dependencies I want to inject my DLL which will do all the dirty work of the reverse engineering.

I think I can load this DLL into the program using LoadLibrary, however when I'm using the DLL I injected to run the main reverse engineered code. Is there a function I can use to call something from the d3d9.dll?

This is because I still need access to the d3d9 library to render things I may want to add on the screen with my injected .dll. I also don't want to just use the d3d9.dll as this will cause problems with loading times, and the point at which memory is changed.

I also don't plan on using DllMain in the DLL, this means I will also need to call a remote function from the d3d9.dll to the injected DLL in order to ensure a safe process start.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, however thanks for any answers.

Comment: Have you looked at using CreateRemoteThread?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said this earlier. However I don't know what I would put in the parameter: lpStartAddress [in]. Would I put the function name (Would be undefined in the d3d9.dll), or a memory address? I really don't know what the start address should be.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why you don't want to have/use Dllmain in your DLL?

Comment: Yes, when I load anything into DllMain it's "too much" information as the injected DLL will basically have a looping thread. This in the past has come back to bite me, when I injected the reverse engineering DLL directly in the program. I had too much information in the DllMain causing the program to suffer from a hault. It wouldn't progress far enough to load the program into a user friendly state. This thread was created using _beginthreadex. No one here seemed to have a solution to that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25815687/1591117 The information was the beginthread, and a startup notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the old days we use to CreateRemoteThread and use LoadLibraryA as the address for lpStartAddress (This address happens to be the same in all processes). The trick was to allocate the DLL name you are injecting using `VirtualAllocEx` and use that as `lpParameter`. Effectively your thread calls LoadLibraryA with the DLL name you want to inject. When the Dll loads Dllmain gets called and you can run code in Dllmain during a time that the dll is being attached (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH).

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) has some very good information on doing just that. However this technique relies on a Dllmain function. If you can use Dllmain then this mechanism may work. A summary of the steps from that article gives an overview:

Now, we can summarize this technique in the following steps:

```
Retrieve a HANDLE to the remote process (OpenProces).
Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected data (VirtualAllocEx).
Write a copy of the initialised INJDATA structure to the allocated memory (WriteProcessMemory).
Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected code.
Write a copy of ThreadFunc to the allocated memory.
Start the remote copy of ThreadFunc via CreateRemoteThread.
Wait until the remote thread terminates (WaitForSingleObject).
Retrieve the result from the remote process (ReadProcessMemory or GetExitCodeThread).
Free the memory allocated in Steps #2 and #4 (VirtualFreeEx).
Close the handles retrieved in Steps #6 and #1 (CloseHandle).
```

I saw your comment about too much information. Not sure I quite understand. However Dllmain has some restrictions like most Win32 API calls can't be used. There are some exceptions and one being CreateThread. Had you considered spinning off a thread to do work? If you use CreateThread in a Dllmain it effectively gets blocked until Dllmain exits. So once Dllmain returns the Thread will execute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow this and give it a try. As you said below however, DllMain is my enemy, with limitations and such. I'll see if I create this thread later, and remotely via the d3d9.dll will work. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: A quick implementation of this has seemed to have done the trick. Thanks for your help and patience with me.